# Adding atribute to object in an Array after Axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

i have an array of objects obtained from an DB "A" and i need to check in another database if i have it in there or not. If i have, i need to add a new atribute with a name value.

getContacts returns the list of contacts with the last message, and getUserInfo checks in another database if the number of the contact exists and its a client. If exists, returns the name.
But im tryng to add the name "mes.nombre=res.data.nombre" and it nevers add.

What im doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
userCtrl.getContacts = async (req,res) => {
let messages = await db.query('SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE message_id IN (SELECT MAX(message_id) FROM mensajes GROUP BY message_from) ORDER BY timestamp DESC',async (err,resp) => {
    if(err){
        console.log({"status":"error","msg":"Error de base de datos"})
    }{
        try {   
                
                const arr = resp.map(async mes => {
                    let from = mes.message_from;
                    let num = from.replace(/\D/g,"");
                    let num2 = num.substr(3);
                    mes.number=num2;
                    let uri = 'http://localhost:3001/message/getUserInfo';
                    let form = {
                        "phone": num2
                    }

                    axios.post(uri,form)
                        .then((res) => {
                            mes.nombre = res.data.nombre;
                        })
                        .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
                });
                await res.json({"status":"ok","msg":"Listado de contactos con último mensaje","info":resp});                     
                                   
            } catch (x){
                res.json({"status":"error","msg":"No existe un usuario con el email seleccionado"});
                console.log(x);
            }
    }
});


userCtrl.getUserInfo = async (req,res) => {
let phone = req.body.phone;
let messages = await db2.query('SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE movil like ?',[phone],(err,resp) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        if(resp.length > 0){
        let name = resp[0].nombre;
        res.json({"nombre":name});
        } else {
            res.json({"nombre":"No"});
        }
    }
});
```

}

This is with Promise.all. Now i could logged the "mes.name" correctly but i cant adding this to the res.json answer.

```
                const arr =Promise.all(resp.map( async mes => {
                    let from = mes.message_from;
                    let num = from.replace(/\D/g,"");
                    let num2 = num.substr(3);
                    mes.number=num2;
                    let uri = 'http://localhost:3001/message/getUserInfo';
                    let form = {
                        "phone": num2
                    }

                    let raro = await axios.post(uri,form);
                    mes.name = await raro.data.nombre;
                    console.log(mes.name);
                }));
                res.json({"status":"ok","msg":"Listado de contactos con último mensaje","info":resp});                     
                                   
            }
```

Comment: `mes.nombre=res.data.nombre` this line won't work for two reasons: 1. it *overwrites* the property every time through the loop, not adds to it. 2. the assignment happens asynchronously, there's no guarantee when (or if!) you'll have the results. Look at Promise.all

Comment: @jaredSmith im not sure how it works but i added Promise.all before the map of the arrays. I wait for the answer of the call to getUserInfo and when i logged it in console, i obtain the expected result, but i'm not getting that in my response of the API.  I adding the parameter in "mes" because i thoutht this is the object, no?

Comment: You are correct about the overwriting, I misread the code, my bad. Your updated version is better but if you want actual data in that Promise.all array you have to *return* what you want from the callback to .map

Comment: Thanks @Jared i already fixed it and moved forward with your comments.